# Mattermost (team chat) - how to post to a channel via curl?

Tags: curl, slack-api, slack, mattermost

We are using `mattermost` as an internally hosted alternative to `slack`.

How can I write to a channel in *mattermost*, for example by a script, using `curl`?

I need to know:

- how to get an "integration key" from mattermost
- format of the `curl` command

An example of my script that works with `slack`:

```
SLACK_URL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/my-long-integration-key'
message='Project XYZ was released successfully.'

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data "{ \"channel\": \"#releases\", \"username\": \"$me\", \"text\": \"$MESSAGE\" }" \
    $SLACK_URL &> /dev/null
```

Indeed there is a [Mattermost API](http://docs.mattermost.com/developer/api.html) (equivalent to `slack-api`) but I am struggling to a good example of what I want to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the format, using `curl` and a json payload:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'payload={"text": "Hello, world!", "username":"xxx", "channel":"yyy"}' \
https://mattermost.intern.mycompany.com/hooks/abcdefg1234567
```

Comment: Where we have to add above command. Place? fyi.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186166/modification-of-the-mattermost-with-gitlab-ci

Comment: It's a unix command so you put it in a bash script. Equivalent commands exist in other scripting languages... take your pick

Comment: means in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Answer (score 2):

For others, I recommend using the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) program in addition to `curl` (your distro probably has a pacakage for it in the standard repos). It will turn any text input into valid JSON data.

E.g. a script called `matmo.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mattermost_hook_url='https://mattermost.example.com/hooks/long-random-hook-id'
jq --slurp --raw-input --compact-output --arg channel "$1" --arg username "$2" '{$channel, $username, text:.}' \
    | curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data @- "$mattermost_hook_url" &> /dev/null
```

Then pipe to it like so:

```sh
command-that-produces-output | ./matmo.sh '#releases' releasebot
```